# can a class be partially mapped by Nhibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have a class which I want to map to DB using NH.
However I want two List properties to be ignored in mapping (both ways - from and to DB).

how can I ignore these two?
omitting them from the hbm.xml doesn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that, when mapping with xml, just omitting the properties is enough to ignore them.

Comment: It's important to note, however, that the ignored properties DO still need to be marked virtual.

Comment: @Brook it is just that I'm getting `Batch update returned unexpected row count from update; actual row count: 0; expected: 1` how can I investigate?

Comment: You can use a profiler to find out what is the SQL being sent and run it manually.